# chance text of search bar in titanium

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

i'm developing an app for Android and IOS in titanium and a need a search bar. in IOS it works fine. the background is white and the text is black but in android the text has the same color as the background (white) so it does not apear.

this is my search bar:

```
var searchBar = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
    barColor : '#FFFFFF',
    backgroundColor : 'transparent',
    borderRadius : 3,
    borderColor : 'black',
    height : 43,
    focusable : true,
    softKeyboardOnFocus : true,
    width : 300,
    top : deviceHeight * 0.12
})
```

how can i change the text color so it is black in android and IOS?

i'm not using the alloy folder

Answer (score 0):

With Android better to use SearchView not SearchBar
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Android.SearchView

It's Appc recommendation

> The SearchBar object is closely modeled on an iOS native search bar. As such, not all features are supported on other platforms. For Android applications, consider using a Titanium.UI.Android.SearchView object instead.
>   http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.SearchBar